# Navigation bar with transparent arrow pointer

Tags: css, html

I am working in an website and I created a navigation bar with an arrow pointing to the active section in the bottom:

[image]

That navigation bar is fixed in the top, and I have a lot of sections with background images and content, I would like to make the arrow transparent to that content **Edit: (to the background image you can see below the navbar)**.

How could I do this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: can you share our code through www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Set the CSS of the background or the image pointer to `opacity: 0.5;`

Comment: you need to look into opacity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an image for that arrow, you could make this image transparent using an image-editing software like Paint.NET (free, http://getpaint.net)

But you could also use CSS and add some `opacity` to your arrow (whether it's an image or not):

```
#arrowselector {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

This would make your arrow half-transparent. Use values from 0.0 (invisible) to 1.0 (fully visible). The opacity-setting can be used in all modern browser. (for more information http://caniuse.com/#search=opacity)

Comment: I am trying to make the arrow transparent to the page background image (not navigation bar), I want to see the background image where the arrow is located right now.

Comment: You can't do this, except you set the background image of the navigation bar (one link) at hover to an image which is colored but at the bottom it has this arrow as free space (so transparent), then it *might* work...

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need I suppose (SCSS + jQuery).
[Navigation bar with transparent arrow pointer](https://codepen.io/RetroCIB/pen/Exgevxw)

```
window.open('https://codepen.io/RetroCIB/pen/Exgevxw', 'Navigation bar with transparent arrow pointer');
```